# View stdout from attached process in Visual Studio?

Tags: c, visual-studio, debugging, stdout, labview

I'm writing a .dll for use as external code under LabVIEW.  I would like to be able to use printf in my dll as a debugging facility. I'm using Attach Process to attach LabVIEW with my .dll code open in VS. In the Output subwindow I see various output about LabVIEW loading various .dll's, but I don't see my output. But it is very clear from program operation that my dll ran.

Is there a way to get stdout output?

Comment: Is the project able to switch to Windows-only [OutputDebugString()](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/outputdebugstring.html)?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the [VsConsoleOutput](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NesviatypaskhaOleksii.VsConsoleOutput) extension.

This extension shows `printf` output for your process (application) in a separate output window. But it still doesn't support x64. I hope the author will update the extension soon, as I'm waiting for this feature myself.